# Why did Sam have to wait for the 'rescuers' to arrive?

Tags: moon-movie

The pod that Sam II went back to Earth in launched from the base on the moon. Why did he have to wait for the rescue team to come in? Surely he could have escaped in the pod at anytime? I thought he was waiting for the rescue ship to come in so he could stow away on that.

Answer (score 5):

The [original script](http://www.screenplaydb.com/film/scripts/moon.pdf) indicates that he didn't *have* to wait until their arrival, he just ran out of time to implement his plan.

> Sam 2 working FAST, a sense of URGENCY. Eliza will be there in a mere
>   90 minutes! It’s coming down to the wire.